# How to set change address with python bitcoinlib

Tags: python, change, python-bitcoinlib

I am using [python's bitcoinlib](https://github.com/1200wd/bitcoinlib) to try and set up payments where a client sends funds to a server and then sends requests signed with their key as proof that the request came from them. The server keeps track of how much funds are remaining. Additionally, a client will be expected to connect to many nodes. I would like to have only one key-address pair to keep track of in the client.

Unless I am mistaken, the easiest way to do this would be to send the change back to the original address in the payment transaction.

However, bitcoinlib's wallet.send and wallet.create_transaction functions don't let you set the change address(es).

Additionally, I tried creating a transaction using transaction_create, taking the change output and creating a new address with that change value being sent to the original address

```
t = w1.transaction_create([(k2.address, 100)], account_id=0)
change = list(filter(lambda x: x.address != k2.address, t.outputs))[0]
new_t = w1.transaction_create([(k2.address, 100), (k1.address, change.value)], account_id=0)
```

But I get a

> bitcoinlib.wallets.WalletError: Not enough unspent transaction outputs found

at the second transaction_create.

How can I set the change address of the transaction?

Also if this is the wrong approach what would be the right one?

Comment: Can you link what "python bitcoinlib" are you using? I took a look at https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib and I cannot find `send` nor `create_transaction` related to the wallet.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't realize there was another package with such a similar name. I edited the question to add the link. Thank you for your for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: For what I can see the library does manage the change outputs for you. They are created to the change addresses of the wallet identified by `account_id`: https://github.com/1200wd/bitcoinlib/blob/a61f490f5ac4c043af01b502d0df43b2c49af7a9/bitcoinlib/wallets.py#L3706-L3710